# What is the return type of stenciljs's render method?

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

What's the return type for the render method in a stenciljs component?

Using eslint with `@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types` complains about the missing return type for the render function and I am not sure how to find out.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to type the render method. The JSX types have changed in the past and might again in the future, but since you're never going to call the method directly anyway (and it doesn't get passed any arguments) I'd suggest adding it to the `allowedNames` (whitelist) config instead.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's what I ended up doing in the end!

Comment: For anybody else searching: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.15.1/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md